# Create a User Defined Language combining 2 languages in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I want to have syntax highlighting for [Volt](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html), the [Phalcon](https://phalconphp.com/en/) template engine, in Notepad++. The closest I have found online is [this one](https://github.com/Banane9/notepadplusplus-twig) for [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) which seems very similar, so I think perhaps that the idea for Volt came from Twig. However, the syntax highlighting provided by the one for Twig doesn't highlight the HTML code that is also in the file.

I want to rewrite the Twig example so that anything inside the Volt tags gets one syntax highlighting (similar to the Twig highlighting) and anything else gets the usual HTML highlighting. In the same manner that a PHP file has PHP highlighting inside `<?php...?>` and HTML highlighting elsewhere.

Can anyone give an example of how to do this? I tried looking at the xml files Notepad++ uses to know what highlighting to use for PHP but couldn't see anything that would explain how the highlighting is different inside and outside the PHP tags.

Comment: This is not possible without programming. If you check Notepad++ source code, you can see that PHP inside HTML is specifically programmed. Linked Q/A: https://superuser.com/q/1213671/287473