# How to enhance Notepad++ to support Laravel blade syntax highlighting in a PHP file?

Tags: notepad++, php, syntax-highlighting

After looking online I cannot find any info on enhancing N++ to support syntax highlighting for [Laravel's Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#blade-templating) syntax (`*.blade.php`).

Example: `demo.blade.php`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know Notepad++ supports user-defined languages to add syntax highlighting support for new file extensions (I have used this before for `*.scss` files).

However, I want to continue using N++'s built in highlighting for `*.php` files and add to it by creating rules to match the Blade syntax within a PHP file. If I was to use N++'s user-defined language functionality for Blade files, I would also have to re-define all the syntax highlighting for PHP syntax.

I have attempted to modify N++'s `langs.xml` and `stylers.xml` files under the PHP definition but with no luck.

Therefore, how would I enhance N++ to provide syntax highlighting support for Blade? This was my [starting point](https://github.com/Medalink/laravel-blade/blob/master/blade.sublime-syntax) which is Blade highlighting in Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible only by writing and compiling your own Notepad++ build along with custom **built-in** language. See Notepad++ source code how other languages (e.g. HTML which can contain JavaScript) are implemented. This cannot be achieved by User-defined language mechanism which is simplified (by design).

There also should be another way by writing a Notepad++ plugin. Several such plugins exist (you can find them using **Plugin Manager**) so you can have a model source code.

If you are attempting to avoid programming for this task, use for example similar editor called [SynWrite](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/synwrite/) which has much more powerful engine for User-defined languages although (of course) it is more difficult to learn. There, the result is achievable.

Here is [similar answer](https://superuser.com/a/1206565/287473).